# Azure deployment failed using Git. Cannot reference custom assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a site to azure from a repository (BitBucket). I get a few deployment errors and I have managed to handle most of them but a few keep nagging me and I do not seem to get my head around them. The log says this:

```
Models\ReflectWebUser.cs(11,63): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\Reflect.Web\Reflect.Web.csproj]
Modules\ApiModules\ReflectUserApiModule.cs(19,59): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUserManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\Reflect.Web\Reflect.Web.csproj]
Modules\ApiModules\ReviewSetupApiModule.cs(16,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUserManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\Reflect.Web\Reflect.Web.csproj]
Modules\ReviewSetupModule.cs(13,53): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUserManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\Reflect.Web\Reflect.Web.csproj]
Models\UserDatabase.cs(13,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUserManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\Reflect.Web\Reflect.Web.csproj]
Models\UserDatabase.cs(14,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUserManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\Reflect.Web\Reflect.Web.csproj]
Modules\UserModule.cs(20,27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUserManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\Reflect.Web\Reflect.Web.csproj]
Modules\HomeModule.cs(15,46): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUserManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\Reflect.Web\Reflect.Web.csproj]
```

Can anyone shine his or her light on why azure can seem to compile this? There are other types in this dll as well that are also referenced but azure does not seem to have a problem with those.
IUser and IUserManager reside in the Reflect.Authenication namespace. Types from Reflect.Business and Reflect.Notification for example are not mentioned in the logs.

Help is much appriciated! :-)

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the full namespace for the IUser and IUserManager Interfaces?

Comment: Is this project build locally? Try cloning the git repo to a different machine/directory and see if it builds there.

Comment: The full namespace is Reflect.Authenication.IUser/IUserManager. Any ideas?